# Is this synchronized code really doing what the author wanted?

Tags: java, synchronization

I am researching a bug that I am pretty sure is timing related because of its use in multiple threads. I think I found code that could potentially be an issue but I was wondering if I could get verification of what I think is going on.

Consider the following code snippet:

```
public MyClass {

    private Map<String, Map<String, String>> managedMap = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<>);

    public purgeOldData() {
      Map<String, Map<String, String>> cpyManagedMap = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<>(managedMap));

      cpyManagedMap.forEach((primaryKey, pkMap) -> {
        Map<String, String> cpyPkMap = new HashMap<>(pkMap);

        cpyPkMap.forEach((secondKey, value) -> {
            checkToPurge(primaryKey, pkMap, secondKey, value);
        });
      });
    }

    private checkToPurge(String primaryKey, Map pkMap, String secondKey, String value) {
        synchronized (managedMap) {
            if (someMethodThatReturnsBoolean()) {
                pkMap.remove(secondKey);

                if (pkMap.isEmpty()) {
                  managedMap.remove(primaryKey);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So managedMap is a class member that is used throughout the class, within synchronized blocks as necessary. In purgeOldData() a copy of managedMap is made and the copy is made synchronized. So cpyManagedMap is a snapshot of managedMap at a specific time.

After the copy is made there are a couple of loops to finally get the data we want to check. This data is sent to the checkToPurge() method. Inside this method that entire method is synchronized on the original managedMap.

Finally we get to my questions:

1. Since cpyManagedMap is a snapshot in time, isn't it possible that managedMap is updated in the time between the copy and the synch block in checkToPurge()? Meaning that the copy is being used to determine whether to remove something from the original managedMap that may have been updated?
2. Does cpyManagedMap really need to be synchronized in this case?
3. Any suggestions as to how to fix the code if indeed my concern about the mamagedMap being potentially updated is true? Should I just synchronize all the code in purgeOldData with the managedMap?

Thanks!

Comment: 1. Yes, I think you are correct.  It is even possible that the `managedMap` is updated by another thread *while the copy is being made* thus resulting in an inconsistent snapshot from the get go.

Comment: 1b.  Using `Collections.synchronizedMap()` on a *local variable* does nothing.  I'm not sure I'm really willing to keep reading, the author was on drugs.  I'd recommend using `synchronized` on all public methods and stop trying to be "clever" about only locking objects when you need to.  I think it's the only thing that's actually going to fix this code.

Comment: markspace...I was confused to, hence the question. Just wanted to make sure it was not just me :-)